# How to add OpenGL support files in codeblocks?

Tags: opengl

[image]

when i try to add the OpenGL files it showing like this

Comment: Did you install the glut library by using apt-get install? And also did you link your glut libraries?

Comment: No .. I dunno how to add those files in Ubuntu.. I'm new here

Comment: Using `apt-get install` to install packages, probably the `freeglut` ones. Depending on the codeblocks install you may need the 32bit version. Alternatively just enter the path probably into the the GLUT location thing (it may need to be in `/usr/lib` or similar)